# How to make objects move in sequential order?

Tags: garrys-mod

I was wondering how to make objects move in a sequential order in Garry's Mod. For example if I was making a house or something, how could I make a door with multiple parts that slide one after another? I've seen a lot of stuff like this in this "Advanced Garrysmod Lake Mansion" video:

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about map-making for the source engine. | Also, try taking a look at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bWIok27J_rg. The moving doors and switches are part of the map, and are not added in through the placement of items, etc, alongside some scripting (that I'm not sure is compatible with other source games... Or only just Garry's mod)

Answer (score 1):

As you probably know, you can move objects by stuff like Hydraulics or Winch. These can be found in vanilla Gmod. Now, I'm not sure if there's a way to create delay there, but you can certainly do that in Wiremod addon. Using a set of differently delayed actions you can move objects sequentially.

Looking at this video, there had to be some Wiremod involved for all the cool stuff with menus and whatnot, so I think you might have to install it too to do as in the video.